# Group data with js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an problem, a need to group some data.
It is worth mentioning that I am using the underscore.js library but anything or any help will help me.
It is also worth mentioning that I am working from node.js.
I would really like someone to help me, because the truth is that I am quite lost and I have already tried and tried libraries but I can't find something that really helps me.  I think I need to make a grouping with ._grouby, but it has not resulted in any.

```js
const data = 
  [ { Nombre: 'Juan 2',    Fecha: '26/09/20', Seccion: 1, Detalle: { Colores: 'Dark',   Valor: 'B1' }} 
  , { Nombre: 'Juan',      Fecha: '25/09/20', Seccion: 1, Detalle: { Colores: 'Light',  Valor: 'A1' }} 
  , { Nombre: 'Alberto 2', Fecha: '21/09/20', Seccion: 2, Detalle: { Colores: 'Blue',   Valor: 'O1' }} 
  , { Nombre: 'Alberto',   Fecha: '22/09/20', Seccion: 2, Detalle: { Colores: 'Orange', Valor: 'F9' }} 
  ] 

const expected_result = 
  [ 
    { Nombre: 'Juan 2'
    , Fecha: '26/09/20'
    , Seccion: 1
    , Detalle: 
      [ { Colores: 'Dark',  Valor: 'B1' } 
      , { Colores: 'Light', Valor: 'A1' } 
      ] 
    } 
  , { Nombre: 'Alberto 2'
    , Fecha: '21/09/20'
    , Seccion: 2
    , Detalle: 
      [ { Colores: 'Blue',   Valor: 'O1' } 
      , { Colores: 'Orange', Valor: 'F9' } 
      ] 
    } 
  ]
```

Comment: tip, loop over it create **object** which the key is the value of `Seccion`, create or append the current item to Detalle array, then do Object.values to get final output.. or loop over and look each time in current/result array which is less efficient.

Comment: Is this some kind of puzzle for which we need to figure out your grouping criteria?  Because it's really not apparent, and you haven't described it.

Answer (score 0):

what can I said  ? free code ?

```js
const data = 
  [ { Nombre: 'Juan 2',    Fecha: '26/09/20', Seccion: 1, Detalle: { Colores: 'Dark',   Valor: 'B1' }} 
  , { Nombre: 'Juan',      Fecha: '25/09/20', Seccion: 1, Detalle: { Colores: 'Light',  Valor: 'A1' }} 
  , { Nombre: 'Alberto 2', Fecha: '21/09/20', Seccion: 2, Detalle: { Colores: 'Blue',   Valor: 'O1' }} 
  , { Nombre: 'Alberto',   Fecha: '22/09/20', Seccion: 2, Detalle: { Colores: 'Orange', Valor: 'F9' }} 
  ] 

const res = data.reduce((a,{ Detalle, ...rest } )=>
  {
  let el = a.find(x=>x.Seccion===rest.Seccion)
  if(!el) a.push(  el = {...rest, Detalle: [] });
  el.Detalle.push({...Detalle})
  return a
  },[])

console.log( JSON.stringify(res,0,2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

with `Defectos`:

```js
const res = data.reduce((a,{ Detalle, Defectos, ...rest } )=>
  {
  let el = a.find(x=>x.Seccion===rest.Seccion)
  if(!el) a.push(  el = {...rest, Detalle: [], Defectos: [] });
  el.Detalle.push({...Detalle})
  el.Defectos.push({...Defectos})
  return a
  },[])
```

Comment: Thanks Mister Jojo, your code your code solved my problem. !!! Thanks very much.

So,

What if I have another field as the "Detalle", let's call it "Defectos", And it would also be similar to "Detalle", how would I fill it in together with the detail? I mean fill in "Detalle" and "
"Defectos"